# persistent php 500 error

Tags: php, arrays, internal-server-error

I'm new in PHP and I'm trying to run a simple php script. It's connecting to a LAPP with PHP 5.6 and I have set a simple test database

```
Peugeot     6666666
Mercedes    57127
Skoda       9000
Volvo       29000
Bentley     350000
Citroen     21000
Hummer      41400
Volkswagen  21600
```

No problems with the database. Problem is with php script which is connecting succesfully to database but displays a persistent 500 error.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
#   $db = pg_connect("sslmode=require host=$host port=5432 dbname=$database user=$user password=$pass");
   if(!$db){
#      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   } else {
#      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }

   $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * from Cars;
EOF;

   $ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($db);
      exit;
   } 
#   $myarray = array()
    while($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)){
      $myarray[] = $row;
   }

#   echo json_encode($myarray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo $myarray
#       echo "Operation done successfully\n";


    pg_close($db);
?>
```

The two lines

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

as well as the line in my php.ini file

```
display_errors = On
```

don't make a difference on having the annoying 500 internal error.
Taking my code manually line by line I noticed that defining the array(    `$myarray = array()`) as well when i echo it(`echo $myarray`) gives me the error. The only workaround is using the `json_encode` which I would like to skip.
So I'm having two questions.

*Why am I still having a general 500 error?

*And why is defining the array and just echo it crashes?

Comment: Check your codes for `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `echo $myarray` doesn't have `;` at end.
Also its good practice to declare your variables before using them.
So, use `$myarray = array();` before using it in while loop.

Comment: Arrghhh.... this semi colon couldn't get php display the rest of errors connecting to database. Silly negligence of me. Thank you